# How WinForms MessageBox internally works

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have an WPF MVVM application which hosts an ActiveX control.

In a point of my application, I connect and disconnect to the ActiveX control. The problem is in the disconnect that is not working and then when trying to connect again it does not work because ActiveX seems blocked (disconnect operation is still pending to be served).

If I put a WinForms MessageBox after disconnecting it works. However If I do not put MessageBox it is not working.

It seems like MessageBox does something internally that allows the disconnect operation to be served.

So I would like to know how MessageBox works and what does MessageBox do internally in order to do the same without the need to show it.

Comment: [Enjoy.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MessageBox.cs)

Comment: Does your ActiveX control ever (try to) display a message box of its own? That would keep it from responding to anything, since it's modal. When you show another message box [it can re-enable the parent](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121226/MessageBoxes-and-worker-threads) (even though it's not supposed to). That would explain the behavior.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's mostly useless, as both Winforms and WPF just end up calling the [WinAPI MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) function almost directly, that's where the real work occurs.

Comment: @Alejandro well, at least it's not all useless. With all useless there is usually just one thing you can do - Go through its clothes and look for loose change.

Comment: MessageBox pumps a message loop. About the exact same thing that Application.Run() does in a WPF app. It is crucial to allow thread-unsafe interface calls to be dispatched, failure to pump causes deadlock. Use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window to have an idea why this blocking call was made from the wrong thread or why the Main thread of your app is no longer in the dispatcher.  And search your solution for inappropriate SetApartmentState() calls.